# cascading dropdown with template using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just trying to explore angularjs and wanted cascaded dropdown with template using ng-include.

```
 <div ng-app="cascadedDropdown">
        <table ng-controller="DynamicBinding">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Country Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-control" ng-include="'../Template/CountryName.html'"></div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <lable>Region Name</lable>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-control" ng-disabled="!countries" ng-model="regions" ng-include="'../Template/RegionName.html'"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <lable>City Name</lable>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-control" ng-disabled="!regions" ng-include="'../Template/CityName.html'"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and template is like

```
<select name="countryCode" id="countryCode" class="text" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```

and similar for region and city.

is it way to achieve it using ng-model or etc..
I tried using other option with template en all but not like below sample code that can solve an issue
http://jsfiddle.net/6eCZC/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you looking for Angular custom directives?

Comment: No, can we use ng-model="country" in template and then in main page access the value of ng-model so base on that can enable/disable region and city dropdown respectively.